# process.env TypeError: Cannot read property 'PATH' of undefined

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, undefined

Why do I get "Cannot read property 'PATH' of undefined" in code like this

```
console.log(process.env.PATH)
```

I expect to get UNIX envirement variable PATH (PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

but my node.js "process.env" variable is undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is I used function "process" further in some code in the same scope:

```
var path = process.env.PATH
// a lot of code
// .. more code
function process(something) 
{ 
     // process something
}
```

Do not do this!